# Swift 2.0 Core Data TableView deleting cells

Tags: swift

We successfully implemented saving and reading from Core Data but we have problems with removing data from Core Data when random cell is deleted.
How to remove data from Core Data when random cell is deleted from tableView??? We typed some code like removing last index from array but it does not work...

2cd Vc

```
    import UIKit
import CoreData

class TableViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

var item = [NSManagedObject] ()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.tableView.delegate = self
    self.tableView.dataSource = self
}

func tableView(tableView:UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section:Int) -> Int
{
    return item.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath)
    let person = item[indexPath.row]
    cell.textLabel!.text = person.valueForKey("username") as? String
    cell.detailTextLabel?.text = person.valueForKey("passwords") as? String

    return cell
}

 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {


// WHAT TO TYPE HERE TO REMOVE DATA FROM CORE DATA WHEN RANDOM CELL IS DELETED
    let context: NSManagedObjectContext = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate).managedObjectContext

    do {
        try context.save()
    } catch _ {
    }
}

override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
    let managedContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Users")

    do {
        let results =
        try managedContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest)
        item = results as! [NSManagedObject]
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("Could not fetch \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found it working like this

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

  switch editingStyle {
    case .Delete:
        // remove the deleted item from the model
        let appDel:AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
        let context:NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext
        context.deleteObject(item[indexPath.row] as NSManagedObject)
        item.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)
        do{
            try context.save()
        }catch{
            print("Error, data not saved!")
        }

        //tableView.reloadData()
        // remove the deleted item from the `UITableView`
        self.tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
    default:
        return

    }
```